# why this selenium error happening, how do i fix it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

patha ="\driver\chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=patha)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 62, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\seleniumproject1\New folder\project1.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=patha)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 69, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception ignored in: <function Service.__del__ at 0x0000013BCA56C400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\seleniumproject1> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/User/Desktop/python/seleniumproject1/New folder/project1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 62, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\seleniumproject1\New folder\project1.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=patha)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 69, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception ignored in: <function Service.__del__ at 0x000001E2240AC400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

what is the reason for this

Comment: I'm guessing `patha ="\driver\chromedriver.exe"` does not exist, your on Windows so use a correct path.

Comment: Also, use 3 backticks ` to format your code.

Comment: What is unclear about "Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Chromedriver for Windows - selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700016/installing-chromedriver-for-windows-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexcept)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the path to the 'chromedriver.exe' file is incorrect or the file does not exist at the specified location. You are using relative path. Use full path, e.g. patha = "C://Users//test//chrome.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Either provide full path of ChromeDriver.exe or put ChromeDriver.exe in same folder where your script is located.

If you have ChromeDriver.exe in same folder, you can use below code,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.option, executable_path="./chromedriver.exe")
```

or if it is located in other directory,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.option, executable_path=r"C:\user\abc\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need to specify any driver paths. It's taken care of by [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/).

Your code can now be

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

You might want/need to take a minute to delete all stray chromedriver instances but then from then on, Selenium will look for a driver and if it doesn't exist, download it for you and use it.